# Issues in string manipulation

Tags: c, gcc

The log.txt file consist of some data. The program looks for ":" and when it find it prints "Done". The program compiles successfully but never prints "Done".

```
char *atrbt ;

    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;

    if (fp = fopen("log.txt", "r+")) {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &atrbt) != EOF) {
            printf("%c", atrbt);
            if(atrbt[i] == ':') {          <------------ Issue
                printf("Done");
            }
            ++i;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your program is mixing up its levels of indirection.  Declare `atrbt` as a `char`, not a `char *`, for the `fscanf()` and `printf()` calls to be correct.  Then in the `if` statement, test `atrbt == ':'`.

Comment: But also consider `fgetc()` instead of `fscanf()` for reading a single character at a time, and `putc()` or `putchar()` for printing one character to the standard output.

Comment: Save time.  Enable compiler warnings.  Well enabled compilers will warn about coding errors like `char *atrbt ; fscanf(fp, "%c", &atrbt)`

Comment: I don't why there is a incrementing variable in the while loop. Declare the variable like this `char atrbt` and `if (atrbt == ':')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing between char and char pointers. One of the possible correct ways could be (code is untested):

```
char atrbt;
FILE *fp;

if (fp = fopen("log.txt", "r+")) {
    while ((atrbt = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", atrbt);
        if(atrbt == ':') {
            printf("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get 'variable is set but not used' warnings for `i`?

Comment: I get the point, but you won't get that error cause we are doing ++i; xD (I have updated the code though)

Comment: It's a fundamental point. Always compile with *warnings enabled* in C. At minimum `-Wall -Wextra` and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. Let the compiler help you make your code better. There are many more warning you can apply. One simple addition is `-pedantic` which will add additional checks for type comparison, etc..